# Adding Grids In codeBehind

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone

To divide a `Grid` into rows we give it row definitions and the `UIElement` that needs to be placed in a particular row in that grid we do it like this:

```
Button Name="Button1" Grid.Row="1"
```

Now suppose I want to do this thing in code behind dynamically then how can we do it.

Thank You.

Comment: I don't know why the down vote, but perhaps the person thought the question was too simplistic (to be honest, it's a borderline case).  But anyway...  dkozi's answer below is right; the WPF grid has attached properties and static methods that are accessible in code behind.  You can use the green checkmark to accept his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do everything from code behind that you can from XAML regarding grids:

```
Grid.SetRow(button, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(button, 1);
Grid.SetRowSpan(button, 2);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(button, 2);

myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
```

etc...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a `Button` in code and add to specific cell of the `Grid` then you can do it like this:

```
var myButton = new Button();
myButton.Content = "myButton";
Grid.SetColumn(myButton, 1);
Grid.SetRow(myButton, 1);
myGrid.Children.Add(myButton);
```