# Display different 'types' in same <DockPanel>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I have the following structure in my XAML:

```
<Window x:class=...>
    <Window.Resources>
        ...
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid name="grid">
        <DockPanel>
            <!-- Some images displayed here -->
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <!-- Some more images displayed here -->
        </DockPanel>
        <TabControl ...>
            <TabItem ...>
                <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
                    <Button Style=...>
                        <Image Sourcec=...>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Style=...>
                        </Image Source=...>
                    </Button>
                    <Grid x:Name="grdBrowserHost" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Margin="0,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Grid>
                </DockPanel>
            </TabItem>
            ...
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I also have the following C# in the 'code-behind' for this class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window{
    ...
    WebKit.WebKitBrowser browser = new WebKit.WebKitBrowser();
            System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

    ...

    public MainWindow(){
        ...
        try{
            browser.Navigate("www.google.com");
            host.Child = browser;

            grdBrowserHost.Children.Add(host);
            browser.Visible = true;
            browser.Navigate("https://www.google.com");
            browser.GetWebView();
            host.Opacity = 255;
            grdBrowserHost.Opacity = 200;
        }catch(Exception e){
            Console.WriteLine("exception caught");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

But for some reason, when I run the application, although the GUI is displayed, with all of the `TabItem`s and `Button`s displayed and functioning correctly, and the images displayed correctly, for some reason, I can't see the `WebKitBrowser` that I've added to the application on the GUI- anyone have any ideas why this is? What do I need to do to get it displayed?

Comment: I don't think _grid.Childred.Add(host)_ is the right syntax. Maybe you should try to add content to a grid, following this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18232222/4198052)

Comment: I have done that, with the line: `grdBrowserHost.Children.Add(host);`, where `grdBrowserHost` is the `grid` that I want to add the `WebKitBrowser` to...

Comment: You can see that I've added the `<Grid>` tag, and named it `grdBrowserHost` below the `<Button>` tags in my XAML...